# Java - RunnableFuture and SortProcessor

Tags: java, multithreading, future

I'm studying some code an here is a method, I 'm not quite sure about what it does:

1) There is a `RunnableFuture`, why is it assigned a `FutureTask`, why not `FutureTask = new Futuretask`?

2) What is meant by `new SortProcessor<E>`, is it from Java or another Class.

```
public synchronized void sort() {
    if (this.internalState == InternalState.READ) throw new IllegalStateException();

    final RunnableFuture<E> leftFuture = new FutureTask<E>(new SortProcessor<E>(this.leftChild));
    final RunnableFuture<E> rightFuture = new FutureTask<E>(new SortProcessor<E>(this.rightChild));

    new Thread(leftFuture, "left-child").start();
    new Thread(rightFuture, "right-child").start();

    try {
        this.leftCache = leftFuture.get();
        this.rightCache = rightFuture.get();
    } catch (final InterruptedException interrupt) {
        throw new ThreadDeath();
    } catch (final ExecutionException exception) {
        final Throwable cause = exception.getCause();
        if (cause instanceof Error) throw (Error) cause;
        if (cause instanceof RuntimeException) throw (RuntimeException) cause;
        throw new AssertionError();
    }

    if (this.leftCache != null | this.rightCache != null) {
        this.internalState = InternalState.READ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RunnableFuture` is an interface and `FutureTask` is a concrete impl of that interface.  It's a good practice to declare variables as an abstract type like this for greater flexibility.

`SortProcessor` must be someones custom class that implements the `Callable` interface in order to be used in the constructor for `FutureTask`.

It looks like two threads are kicking off asynchronous tasks for sorting some type of tree